# Moving Bitmaps in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

My image cant load can someone tell me why please?
I'm trying to change the offset when I press WASD, it will work in Code::Blocks but not the .exe file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <SDL/SDL.h>


int WIDTH = 800;
int HEIGHT = 600;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if (!screen){
        printf("Unable to set 800x600 video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("The Killer Of The Night Pre-Release 0.0.1", NULL);

    SDL_Surface *player = SDL_LoadBMP("lol.bmp");
    if (!player){
        printf("Unable to load the image here's the error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = 100;
    offset.y = 200;

    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            done = true;
        }

        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {

            case SDLK_ESCAPE:

                done = true;
                break;

            case SDLK_w:
                offset.y -= 1;
                break;

            case SDLK_a:
                offset.x -= 1;
                break;

            case SDLK_s:
                offset.y += 1;
                break;

            case SDLK_d:
                offset.x += 1;
                break;

            }

        }



            SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 25,25,255));

            SDL_BlitSurface(player, 0, screen, &offset);

            SDL_Flip(screen);

    }



    return 0;
}
```

It's working fine in Code::Blocks but when I run the .exe file it's not working!?!

Comment: Make sure you have all the image files in the same directory as the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `lol.bmp` in the directory with your exe.

When you run an executable in CodeBlocks, the working directory is the directory of the Code Block project file (.cbp), which is where your `lol.bmp` is located.  You need to put that file in the `bin/Debug/` folder or `bin/Release/` folder depending on your build target.

Answer (score 0):

More info would be nice since "it's not working" doesn't really say what's failing. For example is it a dll error, or like previously stated is lol.bmp not in the proper folder. Also I believe SDL_Rect needs a height and width as well.